# MYSQL order by both Ascending and Descending sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have a mysql table with products.

The products have a category ID and a name.

What I'd like to do is order by category id first descending order and then order by product name ascending order.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `products`.`product_category_id`,`naam` DESC
```

What i'd like is

```
SELECT * FROM `products` ORDER BY `products`.`product_category_id`,`naam` DESC,ASC
```

but that unfortunately doesn't work.

Is this even possible in mysql to define the sorting order of the second sorting column?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can do that in this way:

```
ORDER BY `products`.`product_category_id` DESC ,`naam` ASC
```

Have a look at [`ORDER BY` Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: Then me wonders why this is so hard to find on google... probaly looking with the wrong keywords.

I will accept your answer in a few minute.

Comment: [Searching for Google](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&tbo=d&biw=1280&bih=909&noj=1&sclient=psy-ab&q=order+by+mysql&oq=order+by+mysql&gs_l=serp.3..0i20l2j0i7l7j0.56620.56620.0.56847.1.1.0.0.0.0.165.165.0j1.1.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.86-zknQ5TOc)

Comment: Yea, it gives the order by, been there, but hardly any of the manuals of tutorials highlight how to do two order by's.

Comment: @MichaelDibbets: Did you see [this manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)?

Comment: Now that you have pointed it out to me. All I got when searching for order by's were just normal single column order by instructions or how to order multiple columns by the same as/descending order. I really must thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand what the meaning of ordering with the same column `ASC` and `DESC` in the same `ORDER BY`, but this how you can do it: `naam DESC, naam ASC` like so:

```
ORDER BY `product_category_id` DESC,`naam` DESC, `naam` ASC
```