# How can I use ORDER BY on a column that contains text representing dates?

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql
I have got a table named as  tbl_dealer under which there is a column named createdon which has got values as

```
2015-07-28 22:42:28
2015-07-28 22:58:31
```

How can i get the latest record based on createdon

i have tried as

```
select * from tbl_dealer order by createdon
```

Could you please let me know how to resolve this ??

Comment: You said you've tried it. Did it not work? What was the problem?

Comment: okay , the results aren't sorted.

Comment: please provide an example of sorting result

Comment: That sounds odd. Can we see examples of results without and with the `order` clause?

Comment: Odd indeed. Maybe there's something wrong with the table defintion?

Comment: This is my query what i tried select *
from tbl_dealer
order by STR_TO_DATE(createdon,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') desc; , i am getting Incorrect datetime value: '2015-07-03 16:24:15' for function str_to_time

Comment: Right, so your problem is that you told us the column was typed as a `date`, but it was actually a `char`. Specifying that in the beginning would have been useful...

Comment: And you are not using the format spec of STR_TO_DATE() properly. Please read the documentation. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: possible duplicate of [MYSQL order by both Ascending and Descending sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468781/mysql-order-by-both-ascending-and-descending-sorting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just looking for a list based on newest date just add DESC to your current query.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_dealer ORDER BY createdon DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks i was trying it this way select *
from tbl_dealer
order by STR_TO_DATE(createdon,'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss') desc;

Comment: but i am getting Incorrect datetime value: '2015-07-03 16:24:15' for function str_to_time

Comment: because (we now know that) the date is stored in a char column, this means the results will be ordered by the textual representation of the date (ascii by each digit). luckily, iso dates have a 1:1 correspondence between the actual time value and the whole string's textual sorting order. other formats are nowhere nearly so lenient, so a _properly done_ `cast` or `str_to_date()` would be required for those. i'm not sure this is a complete answer, but nor was the question originally, so i guess jpouliot did what they could with the poor info that existed back then.