# How to fetch mysql data in descending order?

Tags: php, mysql

So my application gets mysql data in json format and displays it in 
id1 to id* 
I have to update my database table every day and I want to show the recent data first, I don't want to change the entire table structure each and every time I update my database.

Is there any way that I can add rows in ascending order and fetch data in descending order so that my app will show the fresh data first?

Here is the encoder:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect("domain", "database user", "password", "database name");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_data WHERE id BETWEEN ($id+1) AND ($id + 10)";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row;    
}

header('Content-Type:Application/json');
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: hint: order by id desc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL order by both Ascending and Descending sorting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13468781/mysql-order-by-both-ascending-and-descending-sorting)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `order by desc` like this

```
Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+10) order by id desc
```

Here your data shorted in descending order. and order follow in id. if you want to do order with any other field. than you can give name of field instead of id.

Answer (score 1):

your code should be like this

```
<?php 

$connection = mysqli_connect("domain","database user","password","database name");
    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $query = "Select * from my_data where id between ($id+1) and ($id+10) order by id desc";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

        $array[] = $row;    
    }
    header('Content-Type:Application/json');
    echo json_encode($array);

 ?>
```

Hope this will help you!!

Answer (score 1):

Use below syntax

`SELECT * FROM Table_Name order by Column_name DESC`

Answer (score 0):

for refference see this :

[SQL Order By](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)